How to load external image in neutralino?
I have an application in which I create a folder and upload images.
When I try to load these images into my application, I get an error message:

http://localhost:4200/my-custom-data/my-custom-image.png 404 (Not Found)

How can I use a folder outside the application to upload my images?

I'm working on an app that plays sounds from disk as part of its functionality. I use the Neutralino.filesystem API (specifically Neutralino.filesystem.readBinaryFile(<path>)).
That returns a blob, but to feed it to the webapp, you need to turn it into a data URI. Then you can make the data URI the source of your image tag.
This is the code I use... note my mime type is always going to be audio, so I am hard coding that part of the mime type.
async function convertAudio( buffer, mimeType ) {
    let binary = '';
    let bytes = new Uint8Array( buffer );
    let len = bytes.byteLength;
    for (var i = 0; i < len; i++) {
        binary += String.fromCharCode( bytes[ i ] );
    }
    let playable = window.btoa( binary );
    let dataURI = `data:audio/${mimeType};base64,${playable}`;
    return dataURI;
}

The buffer is the return value of the Neutralino.filesystem.readBinaryFile operation.
